# Windows Phone push notification multiple Devices in one request

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone

i'm trying to implement push notification for our Windows Phone apps. We have about 40, 50 games on Mobile Phones, each game we have about ~400.000 users on their device.

I read some tutorial about push notification for Windows Phone such as this (http://joashpereira.com/blog/2015/03/18/php-script-to-send-android-ios-and-windwos-phone-push-notification/), but there's a problem is that we can only send push notification to one device per request. If i use this method, our program will process very very slow.

It's not look like Android or IOS, where i can send notification to ~1000 devices per request. That's pretty easier.

Anyone know how i can deal with this problem? Pls Help, thanks.

Comment: We use Microsft Azure to send/manage the notifications. You can send a notification to a specific tag. The devices/clients register their pnshandle (in wp the notification-uri given from the phone) with a tag-array. So you can send a message to multiple clients with only one request. More infos: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-overview/ When this is an option for you, I can write a direct answer here with more infos for a solution with MS-Azure

Comment: Hey Joehl, thanks for pointing me to Microsoft Azure. I did read about their Notification Hub Service, it seems good for our goal. I will look into it more.

Comment: Can we have an option to monitor how many push notifications were sent to a specific tag with Notification Hub ?

Answer (score 1):

[Answer to a comment in the question]

The send method of the NotificationHub returns a [NotificationOutcome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.notificationoutcome.aspx) object. This object contains several informations. Also a `TrackingId` which is a unique identifier which has been generated by the Notification Hub. But at the moment you have no possibility (as far as I know) to get more informations.

You can use the `TrackingId` to contact the azure-support, when you have problems or questions.

The problem is, that azure don't send the notifications directly to the devices. Azure just sends it to the device specific notification server (APNS, GCM, MPNS), and this server decide about the time to send the notificaiton

Look at [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-diagnosing/) at the end (section 'Debug failed notifications/ Review notification outcome' or 'Review telemetry') for more informations.